# file field validation using ValidateThis

Tags: forms, validation, coldfusion

One of my coldfusion projects uses 'FW/1' Framework and 'ValidateThis' as validation framework.

By using this, all input fields are getting validated correctly with no issues. But when it comes to the file field, it gets validated on the client end correctly but the form does not gets submitted. Don't know why this is happening. The details are listed as follows..

> File Field operation : Have to upload images only in "jpeg/jpg" format.

Test/Default.cfm (View Page)

```
<form action="#buildUrl('test.default')#" method="post" 
    enctype="multipart/form-data"  name="frm_test" id="frm_test">

 <div class="field">
     <label for="picture">Profile Picture:</label>
     <input type="file" id="picture" name="picture" value="">
 </div>

<input type="submit" class="ui small button green" name="Submit" value="#rc.Submit#">
</form>
```

validatethis/rules/test.json (rules file)

```
{"validateThis" : {
    "contexts" : [
        {"name":"test","formName":"frm_test"}
    ],
 "objectProperties" : [
{"name":"picture",
            "rules":[
                {"type":"custom","failureMessage":"Please upload jpg/jpeg images only",
                    "params":[
                        {"name":"remoteURL","value":"/ValidateThis/rules/checkformat.cfm"}
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
co}
```

validatethis/rules/checkformat.cfm

```
<cfif len(url.picture)>
<cfset fileEXt = listlast(url.picture,'.')>
<cfif fileEXt EQ 'jpg' OR fileEXt EQ 'jpeg'>
    true
<cfelse>
    false
</cfif>
```

So the above mentioned details are configured for client side validation, and everything works perfect. But during file upload the form validates but not get submitted.

Am I missing anything ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using `method="post"` but checking for a GET `url` param:

```
<cfif len(url.picture)>
```

Try:

```
<cfif len(form.picture)>
    <cfset fileEXt = listlast(form.picture,'.')>
    <cfif fileEXt EQ 'jpg' OR fileEXt EQ 'jpeg'>
        true
    <cfelse>
        false
     </cfif>
</cfif>
```

BTW, here is a bit more robust way to check file uploads [Getting The MetaData For A File Upload In ColdFusion](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2399-Getting-The-MetaData-For-A-File-Upload-In-ColdFusion.htm)